# Is it possible to pass an object to the context?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Preferences class that I have an instance of an I would like to pass it to the build context. How would I do that? It would be nice if this would be available in the context of all my other widgets as well. Is this possible?

```
class Preferences{
  SpeedNotation speedNotation = SpeedNotation.milesPerHour;

  void writeSettings() async{
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setInt('speedNotation', speedNotation.index);
  }

  void readSettings() async{
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    speedNotation = SpeedNotation.values[preferences.getInt('speedNotation') ?? 1];
    print('speed notation = ' + speedNotation.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that what you want to do would benefit of an [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)

Comment: Another way to think about this is that you want to inject that implementation as a service. Consider https://pub.dev/packages/get_it for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). From the Flutter documentation:

> Base class for widgets that efficiently propagate information down the tree.

With an `InheritedWidget`, you can wrap the information you want to pass down the tree in an object that can be accessed from the context of every widget that is a child (directly or indirectly) of the `InheritedWidget` object.

Here is an example of an `InheritedWidget` that could be applied to your case:

```dart
class Example extends InheritedWidget {
  const Example({
    Key key,
    @required this.speedNotation,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : assert(speedNotation != null),
       assert(child != null),
       super(key: key, child: child);

  final SpeedNotation speedNotation;

  static Example of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Example>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Example old) => speedNotation != old.speedNotation;
}
```

With an `InheritedWidget` like that inserted in your widget tree, you can simply do:

```dart
final example = Example.of(context);
final speedNotation = example.speedNotation
```

To access the `speedNotation` from anywhere down the tree, as long as the `context` you are using has the `Example` inherited widget somewhere above it.